# How to obtain the TPR and TNR from keras metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I would like to obtain the True positive rate (TPR) and the True Negative Rate (TNR) in the model.compile() statement as one of the evaluation metrics.

I have tried using the following code:

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ["accuracy", "tpr", "tnr"])
```

However I get an error saying:

> Unknown metric function: tpr

I believe that they are both known metrics in keras so I don't understand this error. Please assist

Comment: What do you mean "I believe"? They are clearly *not*: https://keras.io/metrics/

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I saw this github thread https://github.com/gagneurlab/concise/issues/5 and thought it was possible. I used ConfusionMatrix from the panda_ml library which is very similar to your solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is clear from the relevant [Keras docs](https://keras.io/metrics/), `tpr` & `tnr` are **not** part of the native Keras metrics; there is a relevant [Github thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8657), but the issue is still open.

But for the binary case you seem to work on, it is straightforward to get the required quantities from scikit-learn (you'll need to convert the model outcomes to binary labels, i.e. *not* probabilities); adapting the example from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [1, 1, 1, 0]
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred) # careful with the order of arguments!
tn, fp, fn, tp = cm.ravel()
(tn, fp, fn, tp)
# (0, 2, 1, 1)
```

Having obtained these quantities, it is now straightforward to compute TPR & TNR (see the definitions in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Definitions)):

```
TPR = tp/(tp+fn)
TPR
# 0.5

TNR = tn/(tn+fp)
TNR
# 0.0
```

The multi-class case is a bit more complicated - see my answer in [How to get precision, recall and f-measure from confusion matrix in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100173/how-to-get-precision-recall-and-f-measure-from-confusion-matrix-in-python).