# Roc_curve over number of nearest-neighbors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor, roc, anomaly-detection

I'm struggling to re-implement and catch the results of one of the unsupervised anomaly detections, which are shown below:
[image: img]
The credit of picture to this paper [Histogram-based Outlier Score (HBOS): A fast
Unsupervised Anomaly Detection Algorithm](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.401.5686&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by M. Goldstein & A. Dengel.

The Author of this paper, use 3 datasets which can be founded in [this source](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/OPQMVF) easily including some info in Metadata tab.

```py
#!pip install pyod
#from functions import auc_plot
import numpy as np
list_of_models = ['HBOS_pyod','KNN_pyod', 'KNN_sklearn','LOF_pyod', 'LOF_sklearn']
k = [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70,80, 90, 100]
#k = [3,5,6,7, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
#k = [3,5,6,7, 10,15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 78, 87, 95, 99]
#k = np.arange(5, 100, step=10)
name_target = 'target'
contamination = 0.4
number_of_unique = None

auc_plot(df,name_target,contamination,number_of_unique,list_of_models,k)
```

I downloaded the breast cancer dataset from sklearn and applied those outlier detection algorithms from different packages like [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) and [pyod](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) (e.g. HBOS), but I still couldn't reach this output which is shown in the above picture.

I'm suing this function for plotting so named `functions.py`

```py
def auc_plot(df,name_target,contamination,number_of_unique,list_of_models,k):
    
    from pyod.models.hbos import HBOS
    from pyod.models.knn import KNN 
    from pyod.models.iforest import IForest
    from pyod.models.lof import LOF
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    from xgboost import XGBClassifier
    from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
    from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
    

    from sklearn import metrics

    orig = df.copy()
    #bins = list(range(0,k+1))

    predictions_list = []

    if contamination > 0.5:
      contamination = 0.5

    X, y = df.loc[:, df.columns!= name_target], df[name_target]
    seed = 120
    test_size = 0.3
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed,stratify=y)
    #print('X_test:',X_test.shape,'y_test:',y_test.shape)

#*************************************
    if 'HBOS_pyod' in list_of_models:
      
      predictions_1_j = []
      auc_1_j = []

      for j in range(len(k)):

        model_name_1 = 'HBOS_pyod'
        # train HBOS detector
        clf_name = 'HBOS_pyod'
        clf = HBOS(n_bins=k[j],contamination= contamination)
        #start = time.time()
        clf.fit(X_train)

        # get the prediction on the test data
        y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)  # outlier labels (0 or 1)
        y_test_scores_hbos = clf.decision_function(X_test)  # outlier scores

        predictions = [round(value) for value in y_test_pred]
        for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
          if predictions[i] > 0.5:
            predictions[i]=1
          else:
            predictions[i]=0

        predictions_1_j.append(predictions) 

        # #AUC score
        auc_1 = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)             
        auc_1_j.append(auc_1)
        #print('auc_1_j', auc_1_j)

#***********************************************
    if 'KNN_pyod' in list_of_models:

      from pyod.models.knn import KNN 

      predictions_2_j = []
      auc_2_j = []

      for j in range(len(k)):

        model_name_2 = 'KNN_pyod'
        # train kNN detector
        clf_name = 'KNN_pyod'
        clf = KNN(contamination= contamination,n_neighbors=k[j])

        clf.fit(X_train)

        # get the prediction on the test data
        y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)  # outlier labels (0 or 1)
        y_test_scores_knn = clf.decision_function(X_test)  # outlier scores

        predictions = [round(value) for value in y_test_pred]
        for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
          if predictions[i] > 0.5:
            predictions[i]=1
          else:
            predictions[i]=0

        predictions_2_j.append(predictions)
        
        # #AUC score
        auc_2 = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)     
        auc_2_j.append(auc_2)
        #print('auc_2_j', auc_2_j)

#****************************************************************LOF
    if 'LOF_pyod' in list_of_models:

      #print('******************************************************************LOF_pyod')
      from pyod.models.lof import LOF
      import time

      predictions_4_j = []
      auc_4_j = []

      for j in range(len(k)):

        model_name_4 = 'LOF_pyod'

        # train LOF detector
        clf_name = 'LOF_pyod'
        clf = LOF(n_neighbors=k[j],contamination= contamination)
        #start = time.time()
        clf.fit(X_train)

        # get the prediction on the test data
        y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)  # outlier labels (0 or 1)
        y_test_scores_lof = clf.decision_function(X_test)  # outlier scores
        #****************************************
        predictions = [round(value) for value in y_test_pred]

        for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
          if predictions[i] > 0.5:
            predictions[i]=1
          else:
            predictions[i]=0

        predictions_4_j.append(predictions)

        # #AUC score
        auc_4 = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)     
        auc_4_j.append(auc_4)
        #print('auc_4_j', auc_4_j)

#****************************************************************XBOS
    if 'XBOS' in list_of_models:

      #print('******************************************************************XBOS')
      import time
      #df_2_exist = False

      if number_of_unique != None:
        df_2 = df.copy()

        #remove columns with constant numbers or those columns with unique numbers of < number_of_unique
        cols = df_2.columns
        for i in range(len(cols)):
          if cols[i] != name_target:
            m = df_2[cols[i]].value_counts()
            m = np.array(m)
            if len(m) < number_of_unique:
              print(f'len cols {i}:',len(m), 'droped')
              #print('drope')
              column_name = cols[i]
              df_2=df_2.drop(columns= column_name)

        X_2, y_2= df_2.loc[:, df_2.columns!= name_target], df_2[name_target]
        X_train_2, X_test_2, y_train_2, y_test_2 = train_test_split(X_2, y_2, test_size=0.3, random_state=120,stratify=y_2)

        predictions_5_j = []
        auc_5_j = []

        for j in range(len(k)):
          model_name_5 = 'XBOS'
          #create XBOS model
          clf = xbosmodel.XBOS(n_clusters=k[j],max_iter=1)
          #start = time.time()
          # train XBOS model
          clf.fit(X_train_2)
          
          #predict model
          y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test_2)
          y_test_scores_xbos = clf.fit_predict(X_test_2)
          predictions = [round(value) for value in y_test_pred]
          for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
            if predictions[i] > 0.5:
              predictions[i]=1
            else:
              predictions[i]=0

          predictions_5_j.append(predictions)

          # #AUC score
          auc_5 = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)     
          auc_5_j.append(auc_5)

      else:
        predictions_5_j = []
        auc_5_j = []

        for j in range(len(k)):

          model_name_5 = 'XBOS'
          #create XBOS model
          clf = xbosmodel.XBOS(n_clusters=k[j],max_iter=1)
          start = time.time()
          # train XBOS model
          clf.fit(X_train)

          #predict model
          y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
          y_test_scores_xbos = clf.fit_predict(X_test)
          predictions = [round(value) for value in y_test_pred]
          for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
            if predictions[i] > 0.5:
              predictions[i]=1
            else:
              predictions[i]=0

          predictions_5_j.append(predictions)

          # #AUC score
          auc_5 = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)     
          auc_5_j.append(auc_5)
          #print('auc_5_j', auc_5_j)

#**********************************************************************KNN_sklearn
    if 'KNN_sklearn' in list_of_models:

      #print('*****************************************************************KNN from sklearn lib')
      
      from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
      import time

      predictions_6_j = []
      auc_6_j = []

      for j in range(len(k)):
        model_name_6 = 'KNN_sklearn'
        # train knn detector
        neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k[j])
        neigh.fit(X_train,y_train)

        # get the prediction on the test data
        y_test_pred_6 = neigh.predict(X_test)
        #*****************************************************
        predictions = [round(value) for value in y_test_pred_6]

        for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
          if predictions[i] > 0.5:
            predictions[i]=1
          else:
            predictions[i]=0

        predictions_6_j.append(predictions)
        
        # #AUC score
        auc_6 = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)     
        auc_6_j.append(auc_6)
        #print('auc_6_j', auc_6_j)

#**********************************************************
    if 'LOF_sklearn' in list_of_models:

      #print('*****************************************************************LOF from sklearn lib')
      
      from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
      import time

      predictions_9_j = []
      auc_9_j = []

      for j in range(len(k)):
        model_name_9 = 'LOF_sklearn'
        # train knn detector
        neigh = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=k[j],novelty=True, contamination=contamination)
        start = time.time()
        neigh.fit(X_train)

        # get the prediction on the test data
        y_test_pred_9 = neigh.predict(X_test)

        #*****************************************************
        predictions = [round(value) for value in y_test_pred_9]
        for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
          if predictions[i] > 0.5:
            predictions[i]=1
          else:
            predictions[i]=0

        predictions_9_j.append(predictions)

        # #AUC score
        auc_9 = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)     
        auc_9_j.append(auc_9)

    #print(auc_1_j)

    if 'HBOS_pyod' in list_of_models:
      plt.plot(k,auc_1_j,marker='.',label="HBOS_pyod")

    if 'KNN_pyod' in list_of_models:
      plt.plot(k,auc_2_j,marker='.',label="KNN_pyod")

    if 'LOF_pyod' in list_of_models:
      plt.plot(k,auc_4_j,marker='.',label="LOF_pyod")

    if 'XBOS' in list_of_models:
      plt.plot(k,auc_5_j,marker='.',label="XBOS")

    if 'KNN_sklearn' in list_of_models:
      plt.plot(k,auc_6_j,marker='.',label="KNN_sklearn")

    if 'LOF_sklearn' in list_of_models:
      plt.plot(k,auc_9_j,marker='.',label="LOF_sklearn")      

    plt.title('ROC-Curve')
    plt.ylabel('AUC')
    plt.xlabel('K')
    #plt.axis([0, 15, 0., 1.0])
    #plt.xlim(k)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 100.005, 20))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.005, step=0.05))  # Set label locations
    plt.ylim(0.0, 1.01)
    #plt.legend(loc=0)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,1), loc="upper left")
    plt.show()
```

Download breast cancer wisconsin dataset from sklearn:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import time
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

Bw = load_breast_cancer(
                        return_X_y=False,
                        as_frame=True)
df = Bw.frame
name_target = 'target'

#change types of feature columns
#df['duration']=df['duration'].astype(float)
#df['src_bytes']=df['src_bytes'].astype(float)
#df['dst_bytes']=df['dst_bytes'].astype(float)

num_row , num_colmn = df.shape

#calculate number of classes
classes = df[name_target].unique()
num_class = len(classes)

print(df[name_target].value_counts())

#determine which class is normal (is not anomaly)
label = np.array(df[name_target])
a,b = np.unique(label , return_counts=True)
#print("a is:",a)
#print("b is:",b)
for i in range(len(b)):
  if b[i]== b.max():
    normal = a[i]
    #print('normal:', normal)
  elif b[i] == b.min():
    unnormal = a[i]
    #print('unnorm:' ,unnormal) 

# show anomaly classes
anomaly_class = []
for f in range(len(a)): 
  if a[f] != normal:
    anomaly_class.append(a[f])

# convert dataset classes to 2 classe: normal and unnormal
label = np.where(label != normal, unnormal ,label)
df[name_target]=label

# showing columns's type: numerical or categorical
numeric =0
categoric = 0
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
  df_col = df.iloc[:,i]
  if df_col.dtype == int and df.columns[i] != name_target:
    numeric +=1
  elif df_col.dtype == float and df.columns[i] != name_target:
    numeric += 1
  elif df.columns[i] != name_target:
    categoric += 1

#replace labels with 0 and 1
label = np.where(label == normal, 0 ,1)
df[name_target]=label


# null_check: if more than half of a column was null, then that columns will be droped
# otherwise if number of null was less than half of column, then nulls will replace with mean of that column
test = []
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
  if df.iloc[:,i].isnull().sum() > df.shape[0]//2:
    test.append(i)
  elif df.iloc[:,i].isnull().sum() < df.shape[0]//2 and df.iloc[:,i].isnull().sum() != 0:
    m = df.iloc[:,i].mean()
    df.iloc[:,i] = df.iloc[:,i].replace(to_replace = np.nan, value = m)
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[test])



#calculate anomaly rate 
b = df[name_target].value_counts()
Anomaly_rate= b[1] / (b[0]+b[1])
print('=============Anomaly_rate=================')
print(Anomaly_rate)
contamination= float("{:.4f}".format(Anomaly_rate))
print('=============contamination=================')
print(contamination)
#rename labels column
df = df.rename(columns = {'labels' : 'binary_target'})   

#df.to_csv(f'/content/{dataset_name}.csv', index = False)
```

I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992268/roc-curve-in-sklearn-why-doesnt-it-work-correctly) wasn't useful for this question to get the plot.
So far my output is following:

[image: img]

Please note that this ROC plot is over different K (number of nearest neighbours).

update: I provided with [Google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z6dJY_a3vLTXEZflE5UlG2wfXNr7oxPa?usp=sharing) to troubleshoot faster if someone is interested in running the code.

Comment: You seem to be using a different dataset. Why would you expect to get the same results?

Comment: I used [sklearn's breast cancer dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html), but still, I'm wondering why Roc_curves doesn't look like the one in the paper. At least curves should have a semi-logarithmic shape. Probably my approach to plotting is not correct. Even as you can see, I tried *KNN* and *LOF* algorithms from both *sklearn* & *pyod* packages to ensure that; however it was unsuccessful. Since I'm using the same datasets, getting similar results are not far from expectations.

Comment: You're using hard classifications for AUROC when you need to use probabilities.

Comment: @BenReiniger In my case, I want to apply some algorithms on famous [outlier detection datasets/benchmark](http://odds.cs.stonybrook.edu/) without labels/target column and although the labels are there BUT not for being used, a bit confusing, it is more to **validate** & **plotting purposes** the approaches afterwards to compare different detection models with my own built algorithm. If you mean by *hard classifications* for this analysis.

Comment: I also find working around [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371625/how-to-interpret-auroc-score), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64047/effective-validity-of-auroc-as-performance-measure-what-about-very-high-auroc), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303954/two-questions-how-to-interpret-the-auroc-area-under-the-roc-curve) and this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5). but The plot I questioned is a bit different presented in the paper.

Comment: From the paper, "The receiver operator characteristic (ROC) is generated by **varying the outlier threshold** and the area under the curve (AUC) is used for comparison afterwards." (my emph.). 
 I was wrong to use the word "probabilities", here you need the "outlier score", but it's still the case that the second entry in `roc_auc_score` needs not to have been rounded to 0 or 1.

Comment: @BenReiniger I updated the post with the bounty. If you see the plot in Fig.1 in the paper the author round AUC between 0 & 1 and limits the y-axis between 0.45 and 1.0, that's why I tried to do the same over the BCW dataset unsuccessfully. I provided with Google colab notebook at the end of the post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, one of the main issues is that you're not creating the AUCs correctly.  The ROC curve requires a continuous measure of confidence, not just the hard class predictions, so you should replace all the `predict` calls by `decision_function` or `predict_proba` as available, and drop all of the code that replaces predictions by 0 or 1.

There's at least one other issue: the sklearn `LocalOutlierFactory` uses a reversed sense of inliers: `predict` returns 1 for inliers and -1 for outliers, and the `decision_function` gives higher scores to inliers.  That's why you see the AUCs consistently below 0.5.  Use the negative of the decision function when computing the AUC and this will be fixed.

Here's what I get with those changes, and a few tweaks to plot smaller k-values (except for `BDOS` which cannot take `k<=2`), as well as limiting the y-axis as suggested (now that all the plots will show up in that range):
[image: adjusted image shows higher scores and more variation with k]
Not a perfect replica, but the train/test splits are probably different, I'm not sure if the preprocessing or hyperparameters are identical, ...

[My copy of the notebook.](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/SO72204836_outlierAUCs.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for your input. It wasn't clear in the comment what was your point of view. short question, you said  *"Use the negative of the decision function when computing the AUC, and this will be fixed."* Did you already consider that in your solution offered in the notebook? I also don't understand the different behaviour of LOF from sklearn & pyod packages, while KNN algorithms are much close to each other. Specifically, pyod version is not semi-logarithmic shape as well as HBOS like in the paper. Based on the paper, HBOS should have a great performance.  BTW I used *stratify* in data split.

Comment: Oh, I don't know why pyod's LOF isn't showing up in the chart...I'll investigate later and update.

Comment: Yes, I negated the decision function in the notebook. The HBOS looks qualitatively similar as the paper. Based on the table, it looks as though their plot is for the Pen-global dataset rather than the breast cancer one.

Comment: Aha, the curves for LOF from pyod and sklearn are actually identical, that's why you can't see the green curve.

Comment: I also think they used other datasets, but didn't mention in plot description. I already shared the [Pen-global dataset](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/OPQMVF/KQYDN9&version=1.0) as well as  [Pen-local dataset](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/OPQMVF/CPRXQX&version=1.0). Is it possible to update your answer with the Pen-Global dataset since it is already available? If we reached the results quickly I accept the answer.